# CSS Issue with Device Pixel Ratio for a Dropdown (Select)

Tags: css

I am facing a strange css issue. We have a dropdown on our mobile site page which is working perfectly at a Device Pixel Ratio of 1.

But when we change the device pixel ratio to 2 or greater the dropdown options are displayed partially with a black background.

Here are the screen captures of the site at different DPR's.

**AT DPR 1:** Dropdown at Device Pixel Ratio of 1

[image]

**AT DPR2:** Dropdown with Black Background at a Device Pixel Ratio of 2

[image]

Any help to resolve the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide css and html so it will help to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the width of the drop down container in your css. If you want the width to be always same provided it in Pixels else provide them with percentage.